# Calculate count of number of flips per year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to calculate the count of the number of flips by year but I am having issues at a specific step.

I've created a function to identify flips. (A property was flipped if it was sold within a year of a previous transaction)

I've also calculated the flips and its year for each transaction for each property (columns YearAndFlip?).

Each row represents a property. Each row (property) has one or more transactions. For each transaction, I have it's respective Year as well if the respective transaction was flipped or not.

1 = flip

0 = not flipped

The table looks like this:

```
ID|Trans_0|Trans_1|Trans_2|YearAndFlip?_0|YearAndFlip?_1|YearAndFlip?_2

1 |AYZX   |LKKW   |ZYIL   |2010 0        |2010 1        |2011 0 
2 |AYWW   |MOSL   |ZYWW   |1996 0        |1999 0        |2003 0 
3 |AYLO   |MOSD   |ZYLO   |1996 0        |2001 0        |2001 1 
4 |AKSD   |MWUY   |ZZWW   |2010 0        |2010 1        |2010 1 
5 |AOPT   |MEEY   |ZZYX   |2010 0        |2010 1        |2011 0 
6 |ALLW   |nan    |nan    |2009 0        |nan  0        |nan  0
```

The output should show the count of the number of flips per year. But I am stumped on to proceed from the previous table.

As you can see in this from this dummy table for instance, 1996 had 2 for 0 flips (ID #2 and #3). Also 2010 had 1 for 2 flips (ID #5).

```
Year|Flips|Counts
1996|0    |2
1999|0    |1
2001|1    |1
2003|0    |1
2009|0    |1
2010|1    |2
    |2    |1
2011|0    |2
```

Comment: Why is the year and the flip in the same column, and what are the 3 transaction ID's for? what does this data originally look like?

It would be easier if this was initially one row per transaction..

Comment: Each property has one or more transactions. Each of those transaction ID's represent a specific transaction for each property.

Comment: Yes I do have a table that has one row per transaction.

Comment: The original table has each row indexed by transaction ID and has columns such as the property ID of the transaction, Date of the transaction, and, etc. I tried using the original format but couldn't figure out a solution so the above post is what I came up with.

Comment: Can you show the original dataframe format? or if this info is public then point me to it so I can try and create a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the *YearAndFlip* columns to index, [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) them into separate columns and then use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to count the number of values in each group:

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns.to_list() if c.startswith('YearAndFlip')]
res = df[cols].stack().str.split(expand=True).groupby([0])[1].value_counts()
res.index.rename(['Year', 'Flips'], inplace=True)
res[res.index.get_level_values(0)!='nan']
```

Output:

```
Year  Flips
1996  0        2
1999  0        1
2001  0        1
      1        1
2003  0        1
2009  0        1
2010  1        4
      0        3
2011  0        2
```

Comment: I just started on this. had the same approach :) `df.filter(like='YearAndFlip?').stack().str.split(expand=True).groupby(0)[1].value_counts()` +1

Comment: @anky_91 +1 for `df.filter(like='YearAndFlip?')`, much nicer than my list comprehension